# Python: Get multiple columns from database by filter

Tags: python, django

I want to get multiple columns from File table by filtering it by login_info. For example it will return 2 objects, but how can I handle it without this error *get() returned more than one ParentMystudent -- it returned 2!*
*views.py*

```
mystudent = ParentMystudent.objects.get(parent=request.session['login_info'].get('id'))
query = File.objects.get(studentid=mystudent.mystudent_id)
   if query:
      for obj in query:
         student = Student.objects.get(registerid=obj.studentid_id)
         obj.student = student
   return render(request, 'file.html', {'query': query})
```

*file.html*

```
{% for obj in query %}
   {% if obj in query.all %}
   <tr>
       <td><a href="#" class="fw-bold"></a>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
       <td>{{ obj.soano }}</td>
       <td>{{ obj.student.lrn }}</td>
       <td><span src="{{ obj.file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ obj.student.lastname }}</span></td>
       
   </tr>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried filter(), but I got this: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'mystudent_id'. But mystudent_id is right though, MyParentstudent table has mystudent. I don't know why it shows there is no attribute.

Comment: Wasn't it `studentid`? That's what your example code shows? Where did `mystudent_id` come from?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `mystudent` is in ParentMystudent table. And `studentid` is in File table.

Comment: You used `filter` with `ParentMystudent`? Didn't you **want one** object of that? It's `File` objects that you want multiple of. Please carefully **read** the answers and what they say before using them. In your case you only want to change the `File.objects.get` to `File.objects.filter` Also note that the weird way of annotating the `Student` to the file seems to be implying that you either aren't building relations between your models properly or you aren't utilizing them properly. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter` instead of `get`, while using `get` we get only one record. If there is more than one record, we need to handle this error by using `try-catch`, but in your case, you can do this by simply using `filter`.

I updated the code you shared:

```py
mystudent=ParentMystudent.objects.filter(parent=request.session['login_info'].get('id'))

query = File.objects.filter(studentid=mystudent.mystudent_id)
   if query:
      for obj in query:
         student = Student.objects.filter(registerid=obj.studentid_id)
         obj.student = student
   return render(request, 'file.html', {'query': query})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I changed it into this:
`mystudent = ParentMystudent.objects.filter(parent=request.session['login_info'].get('id'))
        # query = File.objects.filter(studentid=mystudent.mystudent_id)
        if mystudent:
            for obj in mystudent:
                file = File.objects.filter(studentid=obj.mystudent_id)
                obj.file = file`

But on my html, I have obj.file.something, it doesn't display any data. On the other hand, obj.file alone does display this: <QuerySet [<File: File object (4)>]>